# R言語でF検定を行うコードを実装したい（p値の算出など）

Tags: r

## RのF検定について

以下の二つの標本に対するF検定を考えます。

```
data1 = rnorm(5, mean=0, sd=1)
data2 = rnorm(10, mean=0, sd=2)
```

一般的には、以下のようにtest関数でF検定を行います。

```
var.test(data1, data2)
```

出力結果の例を示します。

```
[1] "var.test:"

        F test to compare two variances

data:  data1 and data2
F = 3.4344, num df = 4, denom df = 9, p-value = 0.1149
alternative hypothesis: true ratio of variances is not equal to 1
95 percent confidence interval:
  0.7279282 30.5824393
sample estimates:
ratio of variances
          3.434423
```

現在、このtest関数の内部で行っていることを実装しているところです。
しかし、出力結果中の

- num df
- denom df
- p-value

を求める式がわからずに困っています。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

クラシカルな方法としては、

```
result = var.test(data1, data2)
print(result$statistic)
print(result$parameter["num df"])
print(result$parameter["denom df"])
print(result$p.value)
```

今後のおすすめの方法はbroomを使用することです。

```
require("broom")    # インストール未ならinstall.package("broom")
result = tidy(var.test(data1, data2))
print(result["statistic"])
print(result["num.df"])
print(result["denom.df"])
print(result["p.value"])
```

Comment: もし、"var.test"と同じ物を自分でも作ってみたい、という意味でしたら、```getS3method("var.test", "default")```で実際にRがどう計算しているかソースコードを確認することができます。

Comment: 私の意図はまさしくコメントの方でした。getS3method("var.test", "default")が求めていた答えです。ありがとうございます。